# ¿Por qué tengo un error al importar loader de Django 1.11 y python 2.7.13?

Tags: python, django

Estoy aprendiendo y aplicando **django** a la vez en un proyecto profesional. Al querer ejecutar el servidor de **django**, recibo el siguiente error en consola:

```
(monitorWeb) E:\monitorWeb\src>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at0x000000000630ADD8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "E:\monitorWeb\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "E:\monitorWeb\src\monitorWeb\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
from eventos import views as eventoViews
File "E:\monitorWeb\src\eventos\views.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.template.response import RequestContext, loader
ImportError: cannot import name RequestContext
```

Lo que entiendo es que no puedo importar el loader que se encuentra en django.template, response.

Lo que tengo en el archivo view.py de la aplicación eventos es:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.template.response import RequestContext, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse

import ServiciosMonitor.Servicios as Servicios

# Create your views here.
def eventos(request):
    """Envia a la vista de eventos."""
    try:
        eventos = Servicios.ObtenerEventos()
        ...
```

Y en el archivo urls.py es:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from eventos import views as eventoViews
from usuarios import views as usuarioViews

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^eventos/$', eventoViews.eventos, name='eventos'),
    url(r'usuarios/$', usuarioViews.usuarios, name='usuarios'),
    url(r'^createuser/$', usuarioViews.guardarUsuario, name='createuser'),        
]
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar a resolverlo se lo agradecería demasiado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás importando [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) desde el módulo incorrecto. Para importarlo tienes que hacer:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```